# Sorting options in the flag summary page

Tags: feature-request, flags

It would be amazing if there was a way to sort flags you raised by the time they were handled instead of just the time you flagged.

Under the current system, say I raise 100 flags and they all get handled throughout the next day. However, they don't get handled in the order that I flagged them in. So, when I want to extract useful information out of the commentary that they recieve when getting handled, I have to manually hover over the "time handled" timestamps or otherwise keep track of what I already read. This is tedious.

I propose that a sorting option is added for the flag summary page so that you can choose to view them in the order of "most recently handled first".

Comment: Don’t read too much in the “order handled” timings. I deliberately don’t pick from the top of the pile to minimise clashing with other mods already looking at the flags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't actually care what order my flags are handled in, but I care about what mods write in their responses. In order to parse that correctly, seeing the latest handled flags first helps a lot.

Comment: As Martijn mentions we all usually have different ways of handling flags. My work flow for your flags is a bit different. I go through all your flags once. Handle the easiest ones in the first iteration, handle the next easiest ones in the second and so on. I do some 4~5 parses of all your flags, which is probably why you get a few handled in between. You can just wait until all your flags are handled and then analyze.

Comment: Also: know that you are an outlier. The vast majority of flaggers wouldn’t need this level of sophistication.

Comment: Sounds like either waiting for all to be handled before doing a pass and collecting feedback or user script time

Comment: Unfortunately, this would be non-trivial and somewhat inaccurate to do with a userscript, because the only information in the page wrt. the time the flag was handled is in a form which doesn't give accurate times for anything that was handled less than three days ago. The HTML only has text like "2 days ago" or "5 hours ago", so dates < 3 days ago have a resolution of days or hours. For dates > 3 days ago the data of the hour:minute that it was handled at least exists in the page. Thus, those flags handled >= 3 days ago would be easy to sort with a userscript or bookmarklet.